Bounding box coordinates using yolov8 in google colab for video
My objective is to create a bounding box on a specific car and then trace the bounding box coordinates throughout the video file using yolov8 model. I have tried to first manually select a car from the initial frame and then that car's bounding box coordinates is what i want.
Here is the code for it:
import cv2
import numpy as np
from ultralytics import YOLO
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow

# Load YOLOv8 model
def load_yolov8():
    model = YOLO('yolov8n.pt')  # You can choose a different model like yolov8s.pt, yolov8m.pt, etc.
    return model

# Process frames and get bounding box dimensions
def detect_objects(frame, model):
    results = model(frame)
    return results

# Function to manually select the car in the first frame
def select_car(frame):
    bbox = cv2.selectROI("Select Car", frame, fromCenter=False, showCrosshair=True)
    cv2.destroyWindow("Select Car")
    return bbox

# Track the selected car using a tracker (e.g., CSRT)
def initialize_tracker(frame, bbox):
    tracker = cv2.TrackerCSRT_create()
    tracker.init(frame, bbox)
    return tracker

def main(video_path, interval=30):
    # Load the model
    model = load_yolov8()
    
    # Start video capture
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
    frame_id = 0
    tracker = None
    bbox = None
    
    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if not ret:
            break
        
        if frame_id == 0:
            # Manually select the car in the first frame
            bbox = select_car(frame)
            tracker = initialize_tracker(frame, bbox)
            x, y, w, h = map(int, bbox)
            print(f"Frame {frame_id}: Initial car at (x1: {x}, y1: {y}, x2: {x + w}, y2: {y + h})")
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
            cv2_imshow(frame)
        
        elif frame_id % interval == 0 and tracker:
            # Update the tracker and get the new bounding box
            success, bbox = tracker.update(frame)
            if success:
                x, y, w, h = map(int, bbox)
                print(f"Frame {frame_id}: Car at (x1: {x}, y1: {y}, x2: {x + w}, y2: {y + h})")
                cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
                cv2_imshow(frame)
        
        frame_id += 1
        
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main("/content/videoTest.mp4")


I have the yolov8n.pt file and the video file with proper paths and all.
There are 2 problems that i am facing:

How can i manually select a particular car initially like described above and trace the bounding box coordinates. The problem i faced earlier was that yolov8 will detect many cars simultaneously. I tried tracking one car with a particular confidence level, but the confidence levels keep changing in the video frames, how can i select one car based on this approach or do i have to think in a new direction altoghether?

When I am running it on my google colab, there is a session crashing message due to unknown reasons. I have changed my runtime to T4 GPU beforehand.


Here is the log file ss:

